# How do I work with handlebars (EmberJS)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

So when I click a button on my template it is supposed to change a value and display a list of records on the screen. This is not happening. What am I doing wrong? Below is the code for my controller, model, template and route.

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    usernameIn: '',
    passwordIn: '',
    found: '', 
    display: false,

    actions:{

        renderNotes(){
            this.display = true;
        }
    }

});
```

Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

model()
{
    return this.store.findAll('note');
}

});
```

Template:

```
<h1>Login:</h1>

<h3>Username:</h3>{{input type="text" value = keyInput size="50"}}
<h3>Password:</h3>{{input type="text" value = keyInput size="50"}}
<br>
<br>
<button{{action 'renderNotes'}}>Submit</button>

{{#if display}}
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Note</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each model as |found|}}

        <tr>
            <th>{{found.username}}</th>
            <td>{{found.note}}</td>
        </tr>

    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```

Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

    note: DS.attr('string'),
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For your very simple use-case, rather that creating an action code in *component.js*, you can easily do this in the *template.hbs* if you're using Ember 2+. Here's how:

`<button onclick={{action (mut display) true)}}>Submit</button>`

Comment: How can we make this button to toggle display ?. is this possible without writing actions ?. I am asking this to just to confirm

Comment: Yes, it's possible without writing actions. Just combine the `action` helper with the `mut` helper like I've shown above. You can read more about the `mut` helper [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_mut) and the `action` helper [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_action).

Comment: In your code true is hard-coded. I don't find a way to achieve toggling display property. may be i should ask this in new question though !

Comment: Ah. I see your question now. You can use the inline `if` conditional helper like this: `<button onclick={{action (mut display) (if display false true)}}>Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'set' for setting ember property

```
renderNotes(){
  this.set('display', true);
}
```